# Can't connect to Vagrant using HeidiSQL: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'"

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm using [Scotch Box](https://box.scotch.io/), an awesome Vagrant LAMP stack.

I was able to setup everything on my Macbook in < 5 minutes, but I'm having issues getting it working on my Windows machine.

When I try to connect to the vagrant database using the HeidiSQL client, I receive the following error:

[image]

Below are my connection settings:

[image]

[image]

I've also tried port 22 on the SSH Tunnel tab, and I've double checked my passwords:

*MySQL:* root/root

*Vagrant:* vagrant/vagrant

I've confirmed that the MySQL service is running, and I'm able to connect to MySQL via the command line when I ssh into the Vagrant instance.

Any idea why this isn't working out-of-the-box for me?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here's the `Vagrantfile` if it helps:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

end
```

Comment: how about to change localhost to 192.168.33.10 in your sql setting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No luck, same error.

Comment: Change localhost to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @envysea Tried that. No luck! Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: dont forget that you'll need to add `192.168.33.10 localhost` into your hosts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the version of HeidiSQL I was using. Upgrading to HeidiSQL 9.1 allowed me connect.

Comment: FYI, I'm running 9.3.0.4984 and am having the same issue you outlined above, so either there is a regressive bug or it isn't just the version you were using. :)

Comment: I have HeidiSQL 9.5.0.5272 (64bit) and still have issues with connecting :(

Answer (score 10):

One thing I overlooked is that "local port" under the SSH Tunnel tab is also required. To wrap it all together, there's three key ports to set.

If your Vagrantfile looks kind of like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3310
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.11"
end
```

and Vagrant auto-forwards the SSH port (22) to, say 2222 (you can check this by `vagrant ssh-config`, then the HeidiSQL config should be as follows:

[image: Red brackets highlight fields to change]

As new Vagrant versions use a custom-generated SSH key, you will need that instead of the vagrant/vagrant user/pw combination. The keys can be found in `project location\.vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox`.

This is as of HeidiSQL 9.4.0.5130 (64 Bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: This worked for me. Not using the PPK, but username vagrant, password vagrant. All other settings should be as shown above. And don't forget that Vagrant file adjustment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I still experience this issue in HeidiSQL 9.3.  I've found that suspending and reloading the vagrant box can make it go away.

Comment: Strange! @davemackey commented above that they are also experiencing it in version 9.3, so I'm not sure what the root problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Though i got no luck connecting via MYSQL (TCP/IP) setting, i found a solution to the problem.

You need to connect via MYSQL (ssh tunnel), enter corresponding password, connect with plink (you will find link in HeidiSQL itself) and **set plink timeout to number >10-20**.

Tested it with 9.3 build 5901.

This solution was also mentioned in [scotchbox issue on github](https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box/issues/56#issuecomment-239009230).

Comment: this worked for me, thanks! 

windows 7
heidisql 9.3
vagrant box running ubuntu 14.04
mysql 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Got similar issue but on Ubuntu(using wine). The problem was that we use IP for vagrant virtual machine that starts from "192.".
Solve simply adding host on hosts file as "192.bla.bla.bla bla.com" and use domain "bla.com" instead IP in HeidiSQL "SSH tunnel" page.