# Laravel: Connecting to SQL Database within Vagrant

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vagrant

I have recently started to make the leap from local development using XAMPP to using vagrant, with Laravel's homestead virtual box. All working nicely, but I really don't understand how to get my databases working. There are a few scant mentions of this subject scattered over the internet... so I assume I'm missing something simple.

Here's my previous set-up / workflow:

- Start up XAMPP, including MYSQL server
- View my databases with HeidiSQL, using default login, 'root', '' (password blank)
- Connect with Laravel using the following:

  ```
  'connections' => array(

  'mysql' => array(
      'driver'    => 'mysql',
      'host'      => 'localhost',
      'database'  => 'primary_db',
      'username'  => 'root',
      'password'  => '',
      'charset'   => 'utf8',
      'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
      'prefix'    => '',
  )
  ```

  )

OK- in layman's terms please- now that I'm working with this site in Vagrant, what must I do to connect to this database?

Thanks.

**EDIT** This particular project is running on Laravel 4.2 (so no .env file among other things)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Well, in the main config file the default database is set to MySQL using  'default' => 'mysql'. Is that what you're asking..?

Comment: Laravel doesn't require you to manually connect like that....

Comment: What do you mean by connect to this database ? Do you mean getting your site to connect to the database (both inside the vagrant box), or getting a software like heidisql, installed on your computer, to connect to the database inside the vagrant box ?

Comment: Hi Cithel- well, firstly I want to get the site to connect

Comment: Ok, so when you start the box with vagrant up, it sets environment variables telling laravel to use the config in /app/config/local/database.php. You should have something like that:
`'mysql' => array('driver' => 'mysql',
       'host' => 'localhost',
       'database' => 'homestead',
       'username' => 'homestead',
       'password' => 'secret',
       'charset' => 'utf8',
       'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
       'prefix' => '',),`

Those are the default parameters of the database created inside the vagrant box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the box with vagrant up, it sets environment variables telling laravel to use the config in /app/config/local/database.php.

You should have something like that:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'homestead',
    'username' => 'homestead',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',)
```

Those are the default parameters of the database created inside the vagrant box.

Then if you want to use your old data, you have to make a dump and import it in the new. You can connect to the database inside vagrant with the same credentials. The only thing that changes is the port: Inside the box it is the usual 3306, but homestead creates a binding for the host from 33060 to 3306. So you should use the port 33060 in heidisql to connect and import your old dump.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Yep, I'm beginning to understand now- I've got that in my database.php file exactly as you have it and it's definitely connecting. I think you've solved this particular part of my problem- many thanks. Unfortunately HSQL doesn't seem to be able to connect, similar to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885693/cant-connect-to-vagrant-using-heidisql-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-loca Currently downloading latest HSQL to see if it makes a difference. Have a tick and an upvote at any rate.. :)

Comment: @Inigo I just remembered (it's been a long time since I used Homestead), maybe the ip of the vagrant box isn't 127.0.0.1, [look in the Homestead.yaml file](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/2.0/src/stubs/Homestead.yaml), there should be an IP at the top (probably 192.168.10.10). If I remember correctly, that's the ip you should be using instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Yes, it's 192.168.10.10- pleased to say it's all working nicely now :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using default Homestead settings, try to use these credentials in your `.env` file:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060 // Or other port, whch you have configured
DB_DATABASE=biznes
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm on Laravel 4.2 with this project, so no .env files..

Comment: Then try to use these credentials in your config file.